# How to enable and disable the hyperlink in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, itemtemplate, templatefield

I have a hyperlink in the template field. I want to enable and disable the hyperlink based on its value. Let's say if `Id` is `"ABC"` I want to disable the hyperlink. I tried the code below but it didnt work for me.

```
Enabled='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("Id"))!= "ABC" ? true: false %>'
```

I tried the following in the code behind:

```
protected void gridResult_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) { 
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {  
        HyperLink status = (HyperLink)e.Row.Cells[2].Controls[0];
        if (status != null && status.Text == "ABC") {
            status.Enabled = false; 
        }
    }
}
```

But it is returning `null` every time.

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <% if ( WebApp.Common.Auth.Admin() ) { %>
                                <a href="../../Edit/Default.aspx?<%= WebApp.Edit.Default.P_ID %>=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>&amp;r=<%= buildPostBackPortion() %>"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %> Enabled='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("Id"))!= "ABC" ? true: false %>'
</a>
                            <% } else { %>
                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>
                            <% } %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: show your full templatefield please...

Comment: Naveen, I updated my question with templatefiled. Please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I need to do something as you describe I use the following:

ASPX:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="cell-action"  ItemStyle-CssClass="cell-action">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="viewHyperLink" runat="server" Text="View" />
        <asp:Label ID="messageLabel" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

C#:

```
protected void reportedIssuesGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    RowDataType row;
    HyperLink viewHyperLink;
    Label messageLabel;

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.DataItem is RowDataType) {
        row = (RowDataType)e.Row.DataItem;
        viewHyperLink = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("viewHyperLink");  //Gets the HyperLink
        messageLabel = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("messageLabel");    //Gets the Label
        if (row.Id != "ABC")
        {
            viewHyperLink.Visible = true;
            viewHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "~/Edit/Default.aspx?P_ID" + row.Id;

            messageLabel.Visible = false;
            
        }
        else
        {
            viewHyperLink.Visible = true;

            messageLabel.Visible = true;
            messageLabel.Text = row.Id;
        }
    }
}
```

Where `RowDataType` is the name of the type of the row data.

Comment: Do I need to add any reference inorder to use RowDataType?

Comment: @Ranjith `RowDataType` should be replaced with the type of the data you are binding to the GridView.  For example if you are binding an array of strings to the GridView, then `RowDataType` would be replaced with `string`.